# How to login in my application using Moodle 1.9?

Tags: php, moodle

I want to use my application functionality in Moodle 1.9.

When I do login in Moodle 1.9, then I want automatic login in my application.

Comment: Maybe looking at this question may help you.

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10686956/share-user-login-session-between-cakephp-and-moodle/10699923#10699923][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10686956/share-user-login-session-between-cakephp-and-moodle/10699923#10699923

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you have to authenticate database of Moodle and Your Application..

Then You can use session of Moodle for logging in Your Application...